# Existing navigation properties missing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm currently in the process of checking out the possibilities of OData on an already existing Web Api project. Using Code First, I'm creating all models from scratch so that I have absolute control over them. However, even though I have added navigation properties in the code, some of them are missing in the schema when I'm checking it out through the metadata link OData provides.

For example, I have a User class which inherits from a Person class:

```cs
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(User))]
public abstract class Person
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<int> CountryID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<int> RelationID { get; set; }

    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    public virtual Relation Relation { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I do a GET request on this, using `/User(1284)/Relation` (or `/Country` for that matter) I get exactly the Relation or Country class back that I want. The problem is, however, that I cannot call `/Relation(16)/Country`, because this association is not present.

```cs
[DataContract]
public class Relation
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Number { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Serial { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<int> CountryID { get; set; }

    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    public virtual List<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

But as you can see, in my relation class, there definitely is such a navigation property present. Also, when you look at the DbContext class:

```cs
    public DbSet<Relation> Relations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
```

and WebApiConfig

```cs
    ODataModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    modelBuilder.EntitySet<Relation>("Relations");
    modelBuilder.EntitySet<Country>("Countries");
    modelBuilder.EntitySet<User>("Users");
```

You can see that actually relation and user are almost identical in terms of navigation properties, at least on Country they are identical.

Only, as I said, when I look at the metadata provided by OData itself:

```cs
  <Association Name="TestProject_Models_User_Country_TestProject_Models_Country_CountryPartner">
    <End Type="TestProject.Models.Country" Role="Country" Multiplicity="0..1" />
    <End Type="TestProject.Models.User" Role="CountryPartner" Multiplicity="0..1" />
  </Association>
  <Association Name="TestProject_Models_User_Relation_TestProject_Models_Relation_RelationPartner">
    <End Type="TestProject.Models.Relation" Role="Relation" Multiplicity="0..1" />
    <End Type="TestProject.Models.User" Role="RelationPartner" Multiplicity="0..1" />
  </Association>
```

You can see that User->Country and User->Relation exists, but the associations of Relation to Country and User is missing. In the database, however, these relations do exists and the foreign keys are in place. When I run Update-Database in the NuGet console I also get the notification that there are no code updates to be done.

I've already dropped my entire database and let CodeFirst recreate everything; updated to the latest stable build of OData (from 4.0.0 to 4.0.30506), but alas, nothing is working.

Does anyone have any leads for me to follow? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the $metadata document, does the Relation type definition have a navigation property that references the `TestProject_Models_User_Relation_TestProject_Models_Relation_RelationPartner` association? I'm assuming that the User type definition does have such a navigation property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your class is marked `[DataContract]`, the model builder only picks public properties that are marked `[DataMember]`. So, I am not really sure how the model builder figured out the navigation properties `Country` and `Relation` on `User`.

You can of course explicitly tell the model builder of any navigation properties that it could not infer. Sample code,

```
var relations = modelBuilder.EntitySet<Relation>("Relations");
var countries = modelBuilder.EntitySet<Country>("Countries");
var users = modelBuilder.EntitySet<User>("Users");
users.HasRequiredBinding(u => u.Country, countries);
users.HasRequiredBinding(u => u.Relation, relations);
relations.HasRequiredBinding(r => r.Country, countries);
relations.HasManyBinding(r => r.Users, users);
```

Other way is to add the DataMember attributes on the navigation properties as well to let the model builder figure them automatically.

Comment: Your first suggestion was the one! I was under the assumption that  adding `[DataMember]` to the navigation property would not matter since I saw it not strictly as a property (which is of course stupid). Also because User didn't have those attributes, I thought it would not matter on adding them to Relation. But it did help, thanks a lot!